# Print mutil jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I print Jtable using `table.print();`

however, only one table can print to the one file. Example, pdf file.
I want print mutil Jtable to the one file. But I don't know how.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add the "multi" `JTable`(s) to a single container, and then print the container (instead of trying to concatenate the tables). Something like

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(), true);
panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, table1);
panel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, table2);
panel.printAll(g);
```